# Can I use tie to put Elements of a pair in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, insert, std-pair, tie

So lets say that I have a function like: `pair<int, int> func()` and a `vector<int> vec`. I want to do this:

```
vec.resize(size(vec) + 2U);

tie(*next(rbegin(vec)), *rbegin(vec)) = func();
```

I just feel like this is a really complicated way to write what I'm doing. Is there a way to accomplish this without the `resize` call and all that?

Comment: Which C++ version?

Comment: @MaxLanghof I mean I'm working in C++11. But if you have a better solution for a newer version of C++ I'd still accept that, even though it might not be the best solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

Simple C++17 solution with structured bindings:

```
std::pair<int, int> func();

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.reserve(2);

    const auto [a, b] = func();
    vec.push_back(a);
    vec.push_back(b);
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bS2EN_)

---

C++17 pack expansion solution:

```
const auto vec = std::apply([](auto... xs)
{
    return std::vector{xs...};
}, func());
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5ea0vB)

---

C++17 pack expansion solution (in an existing vector):

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::apply([&vec](auto... xs)
{
    (vec.push_back(xs), ...);
}, func());
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use structured bindings (C++17) and `push_back` instead:

```
auto [elem1, elem2] = func();

vec.push_back(elem1);
vec.push_back(elem2);
```

That's definitely way easier to read.